# Run a command after acquiring IP address

Tags: networking, fedora, dhcp

I would like to run the command `Urlsnarf -n -i p33p1 >> file` when the p33p1 network interface gets its IP address.

Initially I tried to run the command at bootup by adding the a crontab entry `@reboot command`. For some reason, `Urlsnarf` failed to start and I assume it is because the NIC is not ready yet.

I am using Fedora Beefy Miracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `isc-dhcp-client`, provisions are made for "hook scripts" which will run at various stages of the DHCP process, including when an address is acquired.  `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` or similar.

Comment: No, i am not using isc-dhcp-server. This is a plain fedora installation for a pc connected to a NetGear router.

Comment: Haha, big goof on my part.  I meant `isc-dhcp-client` - edited.  Anyway, whatever DHCP client software you are using, look to see if it has this feature.

Comment: No dhclient-enter-hooks.d file under /etc/dhcp. I have no special dhcp client intalled, just the default one.

Comment: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=8513 - I have it on my system but I may have an older version of dhclient ...